# How to keep focus on a field that threw an exception?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have some validation code for the entry of a field (EmployeeID) and when it fails validation I e.Cancel the upcoming events and throw an exception:

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdating<EMPTimeEntries,EMPTimeEntries.employeeID> e)
    {
        DateTime timeNow = PX.Common.PXTimeZoneInfo.Now;

        timeNow = timeNow.AddMinutes(-5).AddHours(4);

        EMPTimeEntries alreadyScanned = SelectFrom<EMPTimeEntries>.
                                        Where<EMPTimeEntries.employeeID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>.
                                        And<EMPTimeEntries.clockTime.IsGreater<@P.AsDateTime>>>.
                                        View.Select(this, e.NewValue, timeNow);
        if ((alreadyScanned == null))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            // Acuminator disable once PX1050 HardcodedStringInLocalizationMethod [Justification]
            throw new PXSetPropertyException<EMPTimeEntries.employeeID>("The Employee has scanned within 5 minutes already!", PXErrorLevel.Error);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the user input progresses though to the next field, I wish to interrupt this behavior and keep focus on the field that failed validation.
[image: Screen view with exception]

As you see in the picture above, employeeID has failed validation the exception and message are thrown, but the focus is on the Employee Name. IF keystrokes matter I typed in 54 and hit tab, I wish for the tab not to happen.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way that I can think is to catch the shown error message from JavaScript and set the focus to the target of the message.

Comment: The real problem here is that even if you set the focus back the error icon and message won't be visible and the user won't understand the reason why the focus is back.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem, since the screen is supposed to be autonomous. I added the exception in "hopes" it would be easier to keep the focus on that control. I kinda solved my problem by making the other two fields unable to receive focus and simply deleting the row instead of throwing an exception. More background: This is to be a fully automated screen, employees come in scan a card and the screen records their time entry (in/out of job site). Seems Acumatica isn't versed in a lot of automations like this?